How to get an array of Mappedin Space coordinates
With the Mappedin SDK, is it possible to get an array for positions of all Spaces or even a list of all the Spaces coordinates at all? Or are coordinates retrieved on a call by call basis?

There isn’t a method that gives you all of them in an array, but you can iterate through the map data in order to get this information. These calls are all made on local cached data, so they’ll be quick (no server calls). Here's a snippet to list the center coordinate of all spaces:
const mapData = await getMapData({
    key: yourKey,
    secret: yourSecret,
    mapId: yourMapId,
});

// Print out the lat/lon center coordinate of each space.
mapData.getByType('space').forEach(space => {
    console.log('Space coordinates: ', space.center.latitude, ', ', space.center.longitude);
});

